# How to run mocha with the tsx TypeScript runner

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, node-tsx

I'm using the [tsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx) command (similar to [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)) to run all my TypeScript code.

How can I use `tsx` to run my Mocha test suite?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `"node-option"` key to your `.mocharc.json`, or to the `"mocha"` section in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "node-option": ["import=tsx"]
}
```

This causes Mocha to run as if you had run it with `node --import=tsx`, or `NODE_OPTIONS="--import=tsx" mocha`.

Note that this requires at Node 18.18.0 or newer. On older Node versions (at least 14.18.0 seems to be required), use the `--loader` option instead:

```
{
  "node-option": ["loader=tsx"]
}
```